# How to paste an equation to a graphics

Tags: notebooks, button

I wonder why `PasteButton["Plot", Plot[\[SelectionPlaceholder], {x, 0, 10}]]`
applied to `x^2` --- highlighted --- doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case you want to plot in place you can use something like:

```
Button["Plot", 
   NotebookWrite[ 
      InputNotebook[],  
      ToBoxes @ Plot[ 
         Evaluate @ ToExpression @ CurrentValue @ "SelectionData", 
         {x, 0, 10}
      ]
   ]
]
```

You may want to add `Method -> "Queued"` for more complicated plot to avoid timeout.

And if you want `x` from the selection to be scoped properly, e.g. to give a plot even if `x` already has a value, then wrap the procedure inside the `Button` with `Block[{x},...]`.

[image]

Comment: On my computer I have the message  Could not parse RowBox[{^,2}] as input.

Comment: Sorry you are right! Have you a solution for the extension of the question ?

Comment: To do the same thing without immediate evaluation in such a way to be abble to make modification to the plot

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki isn't Algohi's answer allowing you that?

Answer (score 7):

According to the documentation, `"PasteButton, evaluates its arguments in an ordinary way, so that expr is immediately evaluated"`

It is like you evaluate `Plot[\[SelectionPlaceholder], {x, 0, 10}]` which will give empty plot.

This could be one solution:

`PasteButton["Plot", Defer[Plot[\[SelectionPlaceholder], {x, 0, 10}]]]`

Comment: Perfect. And How to do tha same  without evaluation --- to be able to change marginaly some parameters ?